# Error because of private access in the autoload_static class of Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am currently working on a Laravel 5.4 project. I am using PHPStorm.

Out of nowhere, today I had this error in the class `autoload_static.php` which is in project/vendor/composer:

```
   public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
            $loader->prefixLengthsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit3a641324e203eb2b3307dce659628bd1::$prefixLengthsPsr4;
            $loader->prefixDirsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit3a641324e203eb2b3307dce659628bd1::$prefixDirsPsr4;
            $loader->prefixesPsr0 = ComposerStaticInit3a641324e203eb2b3307dce659628bd1::$prefixesPsr0;
            $loader->classMap = ComposerStaticInit3a641324e203eb2b3307dce659628bd1::$classMap;

        }, null, ClassLoader::class);
    }
```

There is a red line under each `$loader->variable` that says that it is private and therefore not accesible. Fair enough, I went to the declaration of `ClassLoader` in the same folder which is where this `$loader` object comes from and they are indeed private.

I never change anything in the vendor folder. Everything work just fine. I wonder if anyone knows why this is happening and if I should change them from `private` to `protected` to stop getting the error, or if it will break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will break, it seems. Somebody asked the [same question](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5956) on Github before.

Hope this helps.